# Should I take a separation benefit from a pension or wait until age 55 to get employer matching?

Tags: united-states, pension

I worked at the University of Wisconsin part-time briefly, before Gov. Scott Walker's reforms. As a result I have about $2000 in the pension system, $1000 that I was required to contribute and $1000 of employer matching. I can either take a separation benefit and get my $1000 (plus a few years' worth of interest), or I can leave it there earning decent interest rates (4.8% in 2010) until I am 55 (roughly 25 years from now) and withdraw the whole $2000 plus earnings. It's a fairly small amount of money that I don't need right now, but I am wondering if it would be better to take it out without the employee match, move it into an IRA, and then invest the money myself where I should be able to earn more. The historical return of the S&P 500 is somewhere in the 5–10% range as far as I can tell.

Comment: One point of clarification Craig: do you know if the funds (and particularly the employer matching) have actually been deposited into a separate account that the government can't fool around with? Or is it a general liability of the state backed by their "good faith and credit"? Just asking, since I live in Illinois and I wouldn't trust those guys with one red cent!

Comment: Well, Wisconsin's pension system is [doing quite well](http://www.politifact.com/wisconsin/statements/2013/jan/06/scott-walker/walker-says-wisconsins-pension-system-only-one-cou/), but of course that could change in the next 25 years. I don't know much more than that.

Comment: As a participant in a State of Illinois retirement system where the employer match has _never_ been deposited into a separate account that "the government can't fool around with", I totally agree with @JAGAnalyst's comment. Forget the match, take your $1K and roll it over into an IRA. Incidentally, Illinois retirement systems _do not_ pay out the match as a lump sum distribution; only the employee contribution (plus interest at **reduced rates**) gets paid out as a lump sum. If Wisconsin also pays out the employer match right now, just wait a while; I am sure they will change the rules soon.

Comment: @DilipSarwate If I take a separation benefit (i.e. withdraw the money before age 55) I forfeit the ~$1000 of employer matching. If I could withdraw it all now, including employer matching, I would do it in a heartbeat!

Comment: Yes, and my point (and JAGAnalyst's point and JoeTaxpayer's point) is that if you can withdraw the $1K employee contribution _now_, do it and forego the employer match. Twentyfive years from now, that match might not be there, and even if it is, the rules might have changed to say that you can get a pension (annuity) from whatever the total is, but if you want a lump sum, you get only your contribution plus interest earned, and not the match plus interest. That's the way it works in Illinois, and if Wisconsin is different right now, it might change its rules in the next 25 years.

Comment: Can somebody explain what is meant by "a separate account that the government can't fool around with"? The online account is pathetic, I can't even see my balance. All I know is what I see on my annual statement which says ~$1000 employee contributions, ~$1000 employer matching contributions, and annual interest.

Comment: @Craig W - Craig what I mean is that there is a segregated account that the government must reserve for pension obligations and that they can't spend. In many states, the "matching funds" don't actually exist except as a general liability of the government, i.e. a promise to pay in the future. In other words, in many states, the $1,000.00 in matching isn't actually deposited anywhere, they just promise to pay you later. Unfortunately, many governments have been choosing to break their promises to workers lately when money has gotten tight.

Answer (score 3):

The straight math might favor leaving it, but I'd personally prefer to have it in my control in an IRA. My own employer offered a buyout on the pension program, and the choice between a nice lump sum vs some fixed number 20 years hence was a simple one for me. Both my wife and I (same company) took the lump sum, and never regretted it.